# Showing Credit Card Brand Within TextField with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

I have an input text field for credit card number. I'd like to change its image background whenever a credit card number was inserted. The goal is show the credit card brand within it.

The code I've been working on is:

```
function get_brand_image(){
  $.ajax({
    url: '/cards',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {code: $("#card_brand").val()},
    error: function(response){

    },
    success: function(response){
      $('#card_brand').css({background: "'url("+response['path']+") 0 no-repeat'", 'background-position': 'right'})
    }
  });   
}
```

The above code doesn't add the background image into my text although the second hash parameter ('background-position': 'right') is.

What's strange is that if I put the raw comand:

```
$('#card_brand').css({background: 'url(/assets/cards/visa.png) 0 no-repeat', 'background-position': 'right'})
```

everything is done as it's supposed to.

Am I incurring in any mistake when concatenating the strings?

Any help will be strongly appreciated.

Comment: First check if you are getting the right response and then accessing the right object.. Also the selector used in the raw command and success handler is different (Not sure why you have 2 diff selectors)

Comment: If response is a JSON datatype then shouldn't it be response.path and not response['path']

Comment: $('#card_brand').css  is not the same as  $('#numero_cartao').css

Comment: Can you output a sample of `response`? @NawedKhan, the two are equivalent, either should work.

Comment: I have tried to explain how to concatenate (for beginners) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#card_brand').css({background: 'url('+response['path']+') 0 no-repeat', 'background-position': 'right'});
```

Try this. Supposing you haven't mixed up your 'id's.

also:

```
alert(response['path']);
```

And make sure it's the correct link.

Here is a working jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/9tRhw/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
$('#card_brand').css({background: 'url(' + response["path"] + ') 0 no-repeat', 'background-position': 'right'});
```

**How to learn to concatenate strings & variables (For beginners)**

So basically a simple beginner trick to use variables in a string is to write the whole string as it is -

```
$('#card_brand').css({'background': 'url(img/somepath) 0 no-repeat');
```

Now look at the variable part of it & the single quotes holding the whole string, a) First wrap the variable part with the same quotes you are using in this case its single quotes, so you do this -

```
$('#card_brand').css({'background': 'url('img/somepath') 0 no-repeat');
```

Now you use the concatenate + to wrap the variable part

```
$('#card_brand').css({'background': 'url('+img/somepath+') 0 no-repeat');
```

And finally you replace the string with your variable -

```
var pathVariable = 'img/somepath';
$('#card_brand').css({'background': 'url('+pathVariable+') 0 no-repeat');
```

Answer (score 0):

background: "'url("+response['path']+") 0 no-repeat'"
There seems to be a syntactic error, your code contains both too many and unnecessary quotations marks in your attempt to concatenate the strings. Should be {background: "url("+response['path']+") 0 no-repeat"